# Gulp sass watching even the imports and run the main parent

Tags: sass, gulp

I have this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src( [CONFIG.css.source + '/**/*.scss'].concat(CONFIG.css.ignore) )
        .pipe( watch([CONFIG.css.source + '/**/*.scss'].concat(CONFIG.css.ignore)) )            
        .pipe( sass({errLogToConsole: true}) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(CONFIG.css.dest) )
});
```

With this task, I watch the .scss files and apply the sass on them. The problem is that when I use `@import partial.scss`. These partials are not watched, so I have everytime to save the partial file and then save even the main style.scss file (who calls the import), in order to start the task.

How can I watch even the imports, without have to save both import and importer scss files ?

To make it simple, let's say I have a file *style.scss* that imports *partials/partial.scss*. When I edit and save the partial, only the task on *style.scss* should run.

**Notes:**

`CONFIG.css.ignore` is the path to the partials folder (in this way, they will not be directly watched and saved in the wrong folder), but this also causes the problem that the partials are not watched..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest / use a slightly different approach. I have a sepate task to kick off watchers, e.g.:

```
var pathToAllScssIncludingPartials = '/**/*.scss';

gulp.task('watchStyles', [], function() {
    gulp.watch(pathToAllScssIncludingPartials, ['css']);
});
```

This kicks off `'css'` whenever an input file changes. No need do any `watch` stuff inside the `css` task anymore.

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that the files are watched only on gulp startup, so everytime you create a new file, you have to reload the gulp script.. :( Anyway thank you for the answer

Comment: Oh is that so? I had never realized that :-). We probably don't create enough seperate scss files o.O. I'd think that there's a way to get `gulp.watch` to keep an eye on a folder (incl new/deleted files), but haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: Did you know? I ended up using this approach, way much better. Of course I have to restart the gulp process when I create new files, but also the creation of new files is not so common